# System.ArgumentException: 'Invalid parameter binding'

Tags: c#, .net-core

when i try to retrieve data from procedure that contains cursor

```
 OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
 try
 {
     var conn = new OracleConnection(_connectionString);
     conn.Open();
     cmd.Connection = conn;
     cmd.CommandText = "SP_GETALL_BANK";
     cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

     OracleParameter par = new OracleParameter() { ParameterName = "bnk_limit", Direction = ParameterDirection.Input, OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Int32, Value = 5 };

     cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter { ParameterName = "RecordSet ", OracleDbType = OracleDbType.RefCursor, Direction = ParameterDirection.Output, Value = 0, Size = 200 });
    (https://i.stack.imgur.com/ejb4r.png)
     var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
  }catch(exception ex){}
```

[enter image description here]

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SP_GETALL_BANK( bnk_limit number , RecordSet OUT SYS_REfCURSOR ) 
IS  
BEGIN 
    OPEN RecordSet FOR  
    SELECT * FROM  SP_Banks
    WHERE ROWNUM <=  bnk_limit;
END ;
```

Comment: why there's a space at the end in the "RecordSet " parameter name?

Comment: Please read: [If you're having trouble summarizing the problem, **write the title last** —sometimes, writing the rest of the question first can make it easier to describe the problem.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask#:~:text=If%20you%27re%20having%20trouble%20summarizing%20the%20problem%2C%20write%20the%20title%20last%E2%80%94sometimes%2C%20writing%20the%20rest%20of%20the%20question%20first%20can%20make%20it%20easier%20to%20describe%20the%20problem.)  You have done the opposite 

Comment: The `par` parameter has been created, but is not used anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

The OracleParameter for the RefCursor should not have a "Value" assigned as it is a output parameter, and the "RecordSet " parameter name has an extra space at the end. Here's the corrected version:

```
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();

try
{
    var conn = new OracleConnection(_connectionString);
    conn.Open();
    cmd.Connection = conn;
    cmd.CommandText = "SP_GETALL_BANK";
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    OracleParameter par = new OracleParameter()
    {
        ParameterName = "bnk_limit",
        Direction = ParameterDirection.Input,
        OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Int32,
        Value = 5
    };

    cmd.Parameters.Add(par);

    cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter
    {
        ParameterName = "RecordSet", // Removed extra space
        OracleDbType = OracleDbType.RefCursor,
        Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
    });

    var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    // Process the data if needed
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        // Your data processing logic here
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // Handle exceptions
}
```